# Find out why GNU make remakes a specific file

Tags: debugging, makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to ask GNU make why it thinks it needs to remake a particular target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `make -d` or `make --debug=b` (and then spend the rest of the day going through the output!)

That will print e.g.

```
...
       Prerequisite `foo.o' is newer than target `libfoo.a'.
      Must remake target `libfoo.a'.
  Invoking recipe from Makefile:516 to update target `libfoo.a'.
...
```

See the man page for other options to the `--debug` switch.

Comment: If you have a new-enough GNU make you can use the `--trace` flag, which gives concise information about why a rule is run and where in the makefile the rule was defined.

Comment: Is that really the only way to do this?  I was afraid it might, but I hoped I could get around having to wade through the output of the `-d` option (I don't have `--trace`, unfortunately).

Comment: `--debug=b` outputs considerably less than `-d` and you can just pipe the output to a pager and search for the target you care about

Comment: Do you use make's built-in rules? If you don't, then you can gain some speed and _much_ briefer output from `-d` by also using `-Rr` (only one of those rs is really required, but I can never remember which one).